# Why do I get an error with sql cmdshell when it works in the actual shell?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xp-cmdshell

I run the following:

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo C:'
```

returns 
    Error:  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
    NULL
    NULL

However, hitting the D: drive works just fine.  Also if I just run `fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo C:` from DOS prompt (e.g. regular command shell) - that works fine too.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Works just fine for me with C: in 10.50.2500.0, must be your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no explanation as to *why* it doesn't work, but the following *does* work for me:

```
 EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo C:\'
```

Note the inclusion of the backslash at the end of the query.

Comment: And yes, `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo D:'` without the backslash works for me too. Weird :-/